# JavaScript functions not working onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I am facing a small problem when I am trying to use functions written in JavaScript to change the styles of a `<div>` block, which has an id of 'div4'. I found that this code cannot work normally. The `<div>` was not shown when I ran these codes. Where's the problem?

```js
function togreen() {
  document.getElementById('div4').style.width = '200px';
  document.getElementById('div4').style.height = '200px';
  document.getElementById('div4').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

function tored() {
  var DIV4 = document.getElementById('div4');
  DIV4.style.width = '100px';
] DIV4.style.height = '100px';
DIV4.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
window.onload = function() {
  var DIV = document.getElementById('div4');
  DIV.onmouseover = togreen;
  DIV.onmouseout = tored;
};
```

```html
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's an errant `]` in the code, causing a syntax error.
(Looks like a typo.)

Second, the element has no initial width or height. It will not register any "mouseover" or "mouseout" events because there's nothing to hover over.

Below, I've given it some initial size.
I also defined `DIV4` once at `window.onload` and reference the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) from within the handlers.

```js
function togreen() {
  this.style.width = '200px';
  this.style.height = '200px';
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}

function tored() {
  this.style.width = '100px';
  this.style.height = '100px';
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

window.onload = function() {
  var DIV4 = document.getElementById('div4');
  DIV4.onmouseover = togreen;
  DIV4.onmouseout = tored;
}
```

```css
#div4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Comment: Now I see my problem. Thanks for helping.